# Blur screenshot as you take it on default screenshot app macbook pro

Tags: screen-capture, drawing

I recently got the 2019 MacBook Pro and one thing different from my previous Windows machine is the lack of ShareX (a screenshot utility).

I like to take screenshots and not have them saved locally to my computer (I take hundreds of screenshots daily for work and send it to other people online, and that would take up a lot of space over time which is unnecessary since I can always just search on the messaging platform for that image). I noticed there's an option to save to the clipboard which is perfect except I cannot blur out personal info unless I save it and then edit the info out in the Preview app. Is there anyway to select stuff to blur out? I heard [lightshot screenshot](https://app.prntscr.com/en/index.html) does exactly that but I want to make it so that I can click the screenshot button on my Macbook Pro's touchbar and have it take a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, but I just do not see it as a big deal having the screen shots saved to your local disk, especially in light of the fact that you want to obfuscate some areas of the image before sending. The reason it's not a big deal is you can simply delete the images after a while, either manually or even better programmatically. In other words, setup a _script_ to run e.g. once a day (or however often you want) that deletes any of the screen shots that are older than _x_, whatever you want _x_ to be. This _script_ can be triggered manually or by a _launch agent_, _cronjob_ or **Calendar** _event_.

Comment: ah that's a great idea, my mac has very low space but a script could work (that could answer this question) but imo it wouldnt be the optimal answer since it does take more time to save the image, find the image, open the image and then crop it. The way lightshot works with giving you the option to draw while taking it is great but I don't think  itll work with the screenshot button on my mac's touch bar (3rd button here https://i.imgur.com/Tl0t2tF.png)

Comment: Why there is need to crop the image after taking screenshot? ⌘+⇧+5, select needed area, take screenshot, click on thumbnail appearing on lower right corner of screen to open it, make necessary edits, click on share button to share.

Comment: I am copying it to my system's clipboard instead of saving it to my Desktop or somewhere on my computer. As such, I do not see the thumbnail at the lower right as you suggested